# Can you show rng code running in real time in a game?

Tags: architecture, ios, random, poker

First off, I know almost nothing about game development/rng but I will learn. So apologies for sounding uninformed.

I want to make a sandbox ios game with several activities to do within, one of which is poker, but I want the poker to be infallibly transparent unlike online poker. They wouldn't dare.

So I want to show the rng code to be viewable by players as the hand plays out, so players will know its legit, and can verify after the hand etc if they have concerns, is this possible, can you "show" rng?

Comment: I mean, you can show anything you want. Whether or not that's an effective way to achieve your goals is something else. It looks to me like what you really want to know is "How can I prove to players that my card randomization is fair and unbiased?" — showing code running might not be the most effective (or most cheat-proof) way to accomplish that goal.

Comment: Will people be betting actual money? If so, you'll probably want to talk to a lawyer (IANAL) as there are laws (AFAIK) around gambling. If not, why do you want it to be transparent?

Comment: no, it's in game currency, there are many other things to do in the app to earn money, like fighting games, racing games, speedruns, lots to do besides poker, the only cost would be a small cost for the app itself, if they want to sell their in game currency to each other in the real world that's not my business I'm definitely not getting into the gambling business. I want it to be transparent mostly as a personal goal and as a good gimmick, nobody else will ever do it, a large portion of poker players even play money players have distrust over the servers/dealers, so I want to help them out.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can. There are already online platforms that are doing exactly that, by providing you the hash of the online secret key that is used as the seed for the random generation. Same seed = same random result. Now when the hand/ game is over, you can reveal the original secret. Players can verify by hashing it themselves and compare it to the previous provided hash. There is no problem to give the algorithm away how to create a hand as long as the seed stays secret.

The seed just has to be long enough that people can't brute force it in the time others are playing the game.

Comment: thanks for the reply, there is a site called coin poker that has something where you enter a phrase and later it shows up, good copywriting, but was poor in execution and is a shabby designed site, it failed and has little players, I would prefer something more visible, as it deals the, flop, turn, river, the code is all visible like debugging, maybe I could encrypt the rng so heavily to the extent that only afterwards could it be decrypted and show everyones cards and the randomness of the flop, turn, river, so they will trust the server, they can check themselves but not brute force in time.

Comment: @GGarrett2 you might be interested in [Secure multi-party computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_multi-party_computation). *Don't miss the see also section of the article.*

Comment: @Theraot thanks for the link, lots there to digest, one of the newer cryptocurrency poker sites with this fancy website runs on this mental poker concept https://fair.poker/ problem is, there is 0 players lol.

Comment: while not having poker, pages like primedice or stake use this concept of verification and have their random generation open in the help section

Comment: The problem is, having a deterministic output from a fixed seed does not in any way suggest that algorithm is actually returning pseudo-random numbers. Yes, you can show the hash and then seed that was used, but unless you have the source code and sufficient understanding of RNGs, a seed and hash doesn't indicate that the "RNG" is actually doing what it says on the tin. You'd need a deep understanding of the algorithm for that, so I don't see any simple way to convince a layperson that the RNG is indeed fair.

Comment: Also even with a legit RNG, you'd have to show the entire source code to prove that it's not allowing cheating.

Comment: @bob I would show everything, just encrypted so they can't use it while playing the hand to see everything.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I think if several independant people with deep understanding of rng and mathematics give it the ok that will be enough the put the general playing population at ease, and if they really want to learn it, they are free to do it themselves I may even offer tutorials of how to understand it.

Comment: With poker it's even more complicated, because you might not want to let any player examine all of the other players' cards, as this would expose their playing style, e.g. how often they bluff etc

Comment: @NuclearHoagie "The problem is, having a deterministic output from a fixed seed does not in any way suggest that algorithm is actually returning pseudo-random numbers." Er, having deterministic output from a fixed seed does suggest pseudo-random numbers (as opposed to truly random numbers, which aren't deterministic).  What it doesn't tell you is if the distribution of those pseudo-random numbers is uniform.

Comment: "I would prefer something more visible, as it deals the, flop, turn, river, the code is all visible like debugging" – That wouldn't accomplish anything. You have two kinds of players: the ones who understand how to verify your random number generator, and the ones who don't. For the ones who understand how to verify it, a real-time display would be useless because they could just as easily verify it after the fact. For the ones who don't understand how to verify it, a real-time display would be useless because they would have no way to know that it's an honest description of what's happening.

Comment: @GGarrett2: I think you're using "code" to mean "random seed" (a number) which you want to show to players.  (Or a hash of it).  I found this confusing in the question title, too.  But @ bob means your program's *source* code, like `.cpp` and `.h` files.  Only if other people can audit the source code can they confirm that the numbers shown on screen actually mean anything, otherwise it's still just taking your word for it about how the software works, and how it uses the random numbers.  i.e. showing a hash (and then the actual) RNG seed only really works for open-source software.

Comment: @TannerSwett yeah, I would have to put a tutorial of how to verify the rng for everyone, I don't want any 'trust me I'm a good guy' stuff, I want them to have full agency to verify whatever they want, maybe the real time display is useless if they can truly verify it after the fact and the real time display adds no value, but it's just a little more transparency for the real pessimists and kind of a gimmick that would differentiate my app from others, appreciate the advice on this.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah I can't even call myself a pre-level dev so I must have fumbled the terms, I don't want anyone taking my word for anything, can I publish and allow them to audit, as in inspect, the source code without altering it?

Comment: @codebling everyone's cards would have to be exposed, even burn cards, the players who don't like this won't use the app, ignition/bovada/bodog site allows all players cards even folded ones to be viewed via hand histories, but this is 24 hours later after the hand is played, and that's as far as their transparency goes, I think people wouldn't mind seeing what their opponents had, might add a layer of meta some would appreciate, as well it helps for studying, and video replay studying with all information imo is the best way to get better at poker, kind of reverse engineer poker psychology.

Comment: @GGarrett2: You'd have to ask on opensource.SE, but yes I think some commercial companies have published source code under a license that doesn't grant any rights use a modified copy, or redistribute at all. IIRC, early AT&T Unix was like that - it came with source code, but all you could do was compile it. (You might instead want to consider the GPL - that would let people distribute modified copies as long as they share their changes, so if people want to improve it you both win.  However, the GPL does let people incorporate into something on a cloud server, keeping the code+binary private.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I see, both sound plausible for this project, I will look into both options :)

Comment: @jamesdlin Determinism suggests the numbers are *pseudo*-random at best, but doesn't indicate they're random at all. If I write a function that returns 12 regardless of the seed, or just returns the seed itself, those are both deterministic functions of a seed that cannot be reasonably described as "random" in any way, pseudo or otherwise. My point is that having a deterministic function that maps seed to output doesn't suggest *in any way* that you're looking at some kind of PRNG.

Answer (score 3):

See [mental poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker). That article describes a problem that's a bit harder than the one that you outline, as you are asking merely how to prove to the players that you gave them the "right" cards. For that problem, you can simply post a hash of the deck before the game, then post the deck afterwards. The players can then check that the deck hashes to the correct value.

If the players are really paranoid, however, they may worry that you're in cahoots with one of the players and telling them what cards the other players are getting. They also may worry that the deck isn't being chosen randomly, and merely posting the seed doesn't solve that, as that just raises the question of how the seed is chosen. The above article discusses how it's possible to eliminate even those possibilities.

Comment: I have come across the term mental poker before as another site tried to use it, but they had bad marketing/wanted people to play only in bitcoin so they failed, I may incorporate it, thanks for the synopsis.